# ExcelRun::failed: Type mismatch >> error when calling an Excel macro from Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages, excel, commercial-package, excellink

I have a macro in a module within an Excel file (called "test.xlsm", saved on my desktop) that takes one argument as a string:

```
Sub macro1(str As String)
    Range("A1").Value = str
End Sub
```

Using Mathematic Link for Excel add-in (version 3.5.0), I would like to run this macro directly from Mathematica 10.3:

```
In[1]:= << ExcelLink`
        Needs["ExcelLink`"]
        ExcelOpen["\\\\Mac\\Home\\Desktop\\Test.xlsm"]
        ExcelRun["macro1", "string"]
```

However, when I run this code from within Mathematica, I get the following type mismatch error:

```
Out[2]:= -Book: Test.xlsm-

         ExcelRun::failed: Type mismatch >>
Out[3]:= $Failed
```

When I call the macro from within Excel from another macro, it runs without any error.

I would appreciate any pointers or possible solutions. Thank you.

Comment: @Yves Klett thank you for the quick response. As requested, I supplied all the code which reproduces the problem on my end.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Lucas thank you for the edit, let´s hope someone can help you there. And also a (if somewhat belated) welcome to the site!

Comment: try making and running a macro with no arguments.

Comment: @george2079 thanks for your suggestion. Originally, I had a macro with no arguments and calling it with ExcelRun["macro1"] from Mathematica worked. However, I would also like to have a version of the macro that I could run from Mathematica with arguments. The ExcelLink documentation states this is possible using the general form ExcelRun["macro", arg1, arg2,...].

Comment: @YvesKlett thank you, I hope so too!

Comment: sorry i dont have it to play with. next thing id try would be some other type besides strings.  I looked at the docs and they are pretty sparse, no examples with args..

Comment: @george2079 The string type was the problem! I updated macro1 to have its argument "As Variant" and now ExcelRun["macro1", arg1] works. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Suggestion: You can self-answer to make your solution available to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Excel macro argument type from String to Variant resolved the error:

```
Sub macro1(str As Variant)
    Range("A1").Value = str
End Sub
```

Comment: That's very good to know. Thanks for taking the time to post an answer for posterity! (+1)